# How to unzip password-protected files using SSIS script task without third-party app?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, unzip, password-protection

I want to unzip and extract from a password-protected file using SSIS. I do not want to use any third-party applications and therefore I used script task. I am able to extract if there is no password on the file, however, don't know about password parameter in the same.

I am using the .NET 4.5 framework, with System.IO.Compression and System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, System.IO references added.

This is what works without password:

```
            string ZipFullPath = Dts.Variables["User::FullPathtoZip"].Value.ToString();
            string inputfolder = Dts.Variables["User::TargetFolder"].Value.ToString();

            using (ZipArchive arch = ZipFile.OpenRead(ZipFullPath))
            {
           
                foreach(ZipArchiveEntry entry in arch.Entries)
                {
                    entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(inputfolder, entry.FullName));
                    
                }
            }

            File.Delete(ZipFullPath);
```

Can someone please tell me how I can add a password parameter to the same? New to C#.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a well known 3rd party library, Like as [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). Also, you can get details discussion from [Zip Decompressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160490/decompressing-password-protected-zip-files-with-net-4-5)